# Listviews inside PageViewer - NotifyDatasetChanged not called

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-viewpager

I'm going crazy with my listviews.

I have several listviews ( each one is different) in a ViewPager.

In each row, I have a button to take picture. All the data in my listview is stored in an ArrayList and also stored in Sqlite. At onActivityResult, I set my values in db, modificate the  ArrayList that I use for my adapter, and call notifyDataSetChanged, so that I could change the button icon ( to show pic has been taken).

I'm very close to do it. When I change page inside the viewpager, bitmap does not change ( Because getView is not called), but when I scroll my listview so the row disappears and then come back, bitmap is changing ( Because I use holder pattern, so getView get called.

My adapter take as param the variable Metrica :

```
public class Metrica {
private int id;
private int clienteId;
private String description;
private int tipo;
private int proyectoProductoId;
private ArrayList<Formulario> lForms; // <-- this is the arraylist which populate the LV
[getters and setters...] 
}
```

the Formulario object :

```
public class Formulario {
private int id;
private int capturaId;
private Producto producto;
private String cantidad; // qty
private String imagen; // pic
private boolean picTaken = false;
private int sync;
}
```

The problem I have is only when I take picture, ie in onActivityResult.

Here is the Activity code :

```
public class MetricaTabs extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {
    static ArrayList<Metrica> lMetricas;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    public static Context ctx;
    private int metricaId;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    static ListView lstForm;
    Metrica metrica;
    static EditText transparentEt;
    FormsAdapter adbForm;
    public static Uri imageFileUri;
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    private static int idCaptura;
    private int mAction;
    int numTab;
    private final int TAKE_PIC_FORM = 1000;
    ProgressDialog pd; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_metrica_tabs);
        ctx = this;

        FormHandler fh = new FormHandler(ctx);
        MetricaHandler mh = new MetricaHandler(ctx);

        // I should optimize this with a join
        lMetricas = mh.getAllMetricas();
        int i = 0;
        for (Metrica m : lMetricas) {
            ArrayList<Formulario> lForms = fh.getAllForms(m.getId(), idCaptura);
            lMetricas.get(i).setlForms(lForms);
            i++;
        }

        fh.close();
        mh.close();


        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

                    }
                });

        mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action
        // bar.
        for (int j = 0; j < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); j++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(j))
                    .setTabListener(MetricaTabs.this));
        }

    }

    private void initDatos() {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String activityName = getClass().getSimpleName().toString();
        prefs.edit().putString("FrontActivity", activityName).commit();
        idCaptura = prefs.getInt("capturaId", 0);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case TAKE_PIC_FORM:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                mAction = TAKE_PIC_FORM;
                int position = prefs.getInt("positionInList", 0);
                metricaId = prefs.getInt("metricaId", 0);
                String marca = prefs.getString("marca", null);
                int proyectoproducto = prefs.getInt("proyectoproducto", 0);
                String producto = prefs.getString("producto", null);
                prefs.edit().remove("positionInList").commit();
                prefs.edit().remove("metricaId").commit();
                prefs.edit().remove("marca").commit();
                prefs.edit().remove("producto").commit();

                FormHandler fh = new FormHandler(ctx);
                String picName = RutaActivity.getPicName(mAction, idCaptura,
                        metricaId, proyectoproducto);
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                savePicture(mAction, bmp);

                // Insert or update in sqlite

                Formulario form = new Formulario();
                form.setImagen(picName);
                form.setCapturaId(idCaptura);

                Producto p = new Producto();
                p.setId(proyectoproducto);
                p.setMarca(marca);
                p.setMetricaId(metricaId);
                p.setProducto(producto);

                form.setProducto(p);

                form.setSync(0);
                boolean existForm = fh.existForm(form);
                if (!existForm)
                    fh.addForm(form);
                else
                    fh.updateForm(form);



                metrica = lMetricas.get(numTab);
                metrica.getlForms().set(position, form);
                lMetricas.set(numTab, metrica);
                // If I don't put this line, we work in the Adapter of the second Tab
                adbForm = new FormsAdapter(this, 0, metrica, idCaptura);
                adbForm.setMetrica(metrica);
                adbForm.notifyDatasetChanged(); // <-- ### This doesn't do anything ###
                fh.close();
            }
            break;

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        numTab = tab.getPosition();
        prefs.edit().putInt("numTab", numTab).commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
     * app
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", imageFileUri);
    }

    /*
     * Here we restore the fileUri again
     */
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        imageFileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");

    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            if (lMetricas != null) {
                return lMetricas.size();
            }
            return 0;

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            return lMetricas.get(position).getDescription().toUpperCase(l);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends
            android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String POSITION = "pos";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int numTab) {

            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            args.putInt(POSITION, numTab);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_metrica_tabs,
                    container, false);
            lstForm = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_form);
            transparentEt = (EditText) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.transparentEt);
            int numTab = getArguments().getInt(POSITION);
            // Get the data
            Metrica metrica = new Metrica();
            if (lMetricas != null && lMetricas.size() > 0) {
                metrica = lMetricas.get(numTab);
            }

            FormsAdapter adbForm = new FormsAdapter(getActivity(), 0, metrica, idCaptura);
            lstForm.setAdapter(adbForm);

            adbForm.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

And here is the complete code for my custom adapter using holder Pattern:

public class FormsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private ArrayList lForm;
    private Context ctx;
    private int metricaId, capturaId;
    private Metrica metrica;
    public static int TAKE_PIC_REQUEST = 1000;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

```
public int getMetricaId() {
    return metricaId;
}

public void setMetricaId(int metricaId) {
    this.metricaId = metricaId;
}

public FormsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Metrica met,
        int cId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, met.getlForms());

    setMetrica(met);
    lForm = met.getlForms();
    ctx = context;
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    metricaId = getMetrica().getId();
    capturaId = cId;
    this.setlForm(lForm);
}

public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return getCount();
}

public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

public int getCount() {
    return getlForm().size();
}

public Formulario getItem(Formulario form) {
    return form;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView item;
    public EditText valor;
    public ImageView imgCam;
    public Button listaCerrada;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    final String marca;
    final String producto;
    int tipo;
    try {
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_lista_form, null);

            tipo = getMetrica().getTipo();
            holder.item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);

            holder.valor = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.valor);
            holder.valor.setTag(position);

            holder.listaCerrada = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listaCerrada);
            holder.listaCerrada.setTag(position);

            if (tipo == 1) {
                holder.valor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.listaCerrada.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.valor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.listaCerrada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.listaCerrada.getTag(position);

            }

            holder.imgCam = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.cambutton);

            marca = getlForm().get(position).getProducto().getMarca();
            producto = getlForm().get(position).getProducto().getProducto();
            final int productoId = getlForm().get(position).getProducto()
                    .getId();
            String valor = getlForm().get(position).getCantidad();
            String datoValido = getlForm().get(position).getProducto()
                    .getDatoValido();
            if (valor == null || valor.equals("null"))
                valor = "";
            holder.item.setText(marca + "\n" + producto);
            holder.valor.setText(valor);
            holder.listaCerrada.setText(valor);


            holder.imgCam.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    prefs.edit().putInt("positionInList", position)
                            .commit();
                    prefs.edit().putInt("metricaId", metricaId).commit();
                    prefs.edit().putString("marca", marca).commit();
                    prefs.edit().putString("producto", producto).commit();
                    prefs.edit().putInt("proyectoproducto", productoId)
                            .commit();
                    takePic(TAKE_PIC_REQUEST);
                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            Formulario f = lForm.get(position);
            String cantidad = f.getCantidad();
            holder.valor.setText(cantidad);
            holder.listaCerrada.setText(cantidad);
        }

        String fotoName = getlForm().get(position).getImagen();

        if (fotoName != null) {
            Drawable myIcon = ctx.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.ic_action_device_access_camera_done);
            holder.imgCam.setImageDrawable(myIcon);
        } else {
            // holder.imgCam.setEnabled(true);
            Drawable myIcon = ctx.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.ic_action_device_access_camera);
            holder.imgCam.setImageDrawable(myIcon);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertView;
}

// Code : take pic request

private void takePic(int code) {
    MetricaTabs.imageFileUri = ctx.getContentResolver().insert(
            Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
    Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    ((MetricaTabs) ctx).setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
    ((MetricaTabs) ctx).startActivityForResult(i, code);

}

public ArrayList<Formulario> getlForm() {
    return lForm;
}

public void setlForm(ArrayList<Formulario> lForm) {
    this.lForm = lForm;
}

public Metrica getMetrica() {
    return metrica;
}

public void setMetrica(Metrica metrica) {
    this.metrica = metrica;
}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, I don't know how to fix this one, it's been several days spent in this one... :(

Answer (score 0):

It resolved alone, I don't know what were the cause, today I ran the app and it was working... With that code. I have no clue what was wrong but....God exists!